# What is the intuitive of the perspective of a function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I was reading the book  convex optimization by Boyd and Vandenberghe,while reading the chapter about convex functions,there is a part about operations that preserves convexity and the perspective of a function is one of those operations,according to the book:

[image: def of perspective of a function]

I understand the definition and the proof why it preserves convexity,but in the earlier chapter there is a perspective function

[image: the definition of perspective function and its intuitive]

I find these two functions very similar and i like the intuitive it gives about the perspective function,so I just wonder  is there an intuitive understanding of the the perspective of a function and is it a generalized form of the perspective function?

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking?

Comment: well,sorry if i didn't express clearly,I just want an analog intuitive understanding for the perspective of a function ,like the pin-hole story for perspective function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the perspective function $P$ is like the action of a pinhole camera, then the perspective of a function $f$ is the function $g$ whose graph when viewed through a pinhole camera looks like the graph of $f$. This is like the action of a projector, or a laser light show.

Briefly, $(\mathbf x,t,y)$ is in the graph of $g$ if and only if $P(\mathbf x,y,t) = (\mathbf x,y)/t$ is in the graph of $f$. (Note that the coordinates have been rearranged slightly to make sure that perspective is applied along the $t$ axis.)

All this makes more sense if you first define the perspective of a set $\mathcal S\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ as the set of points in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ which the perspective function maps into $\mathcal S$, show that this operation preserves convexity of sets, and apply it to the epigraph of $f$. This is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: thanks a lot,it really helped!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative description of the function $g$ is the 
positively homogeneous convex function generated by $h$, where
$h(x,t) = \begin{cases} f(x), & t = 1 \\
+\infty, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$. (See Rockafellar's "Convex Analysis".)

The operation of generating the positively homogeneous convex function is
conceptually straightforward and (in my opinion) clarifies the connection to the
perspective view.

The positively homogeneous convex function $g$ generated by a convex function $h$ is created
as follows:

First create the convex cone generated by the epigraph of $h$, $H = \operatorname{cone} ( \operatorname{epi} h)$, and then define $g$ as the function whose epigraph is $H$.

Note that $((x,t), \alpha) \in \operatorname{epi} g $ **iff** there exists $s>0$ such that $st =1$, $f(sx) \le s \alpha$ **iff**
$t f({1 \over t} x) \le \alpha$

Comment: I'm confused by your construction of h(x),it seems like you just lift f to a higher dimension with an additional axiom t,and along the t axis,except for t=1,all of the h took the infinite value.why construct this way?

Comment: It shows an alternative definition of the perspective of $f$ based on cones, which may help with intuition and shows immediately why it s convex. Furthermore, $((x,t),\alpha) \in \operatorname{epi} g$  **iff** $(P(x,t),{\alpha \over t}) \in \operatorname{epi} f$, so it connects the operator $P$ with $g$ in some way.